# Training a machine learning classifier using weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, smo

I am doing a project on identifying the emotions in the tweets. I have a tweet dataset of around half million. I am using weka.classifiers.functions.SMO as the machine learning classifier. I exactly have 10577 feature words which means every tweet's feature vector will have 10577 attributes plus one more for specifying the CLASS.

I am working on windows environment. I am performing my training on 16GB system. But still I am getting "outofmemoryerror java heap space" error. The size of my training set is around 8MB. I have tried increasing the heap size in weka runconfiguration.ini as well as the -Xmx option in java.
Is there any way for training SMO classifier for a large dataset or it is possible to train the SMO classifier incrementally?

Comment: I am using sparse instance in weka and still running out of memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems while using Weka, i guess standart JVM cannot handle such huge space requirements. May be there are other ways but when i googled it i saw someone recommended using Oracle JRockit as JVM. When i installed it my problem solved is instantly. May be you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try out using jRockot.